# Comparing nested structures of arrays in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, nested

Good evening everyone,

I am comparing nested structures of two arrays of the same length (i.e.: [ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 2, 2 ], 2 ] )  by checking for the type and length equality as follows:

```
def array_structure(array1, array2):
  for i in range(len(array1)):
    if type(array1[i]) == type(array2[i]):
        if isinstance(array1[i], int) == False:
            if len(array1[i]) == len(array2[i]):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif len(str(array1[i])) == len(str(array2[i])):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

The function should return True or False whether the nested structures of the arrays are equal or not.

My attemp works for some arrays, but I'm feeling like I'm missing the point so I would appreciate any help to understand and find a more pythonic way to code this and improve the logical approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` and `all`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def compare(a, b):
   if not isinstance(a, list) or not isinstance(b, list):
      return a == b
   return all(compare(j, k) for j, k in zip_longest(a, b))

print(compare([[1, [2, [3, 4]]]], [[1, [2, [3, 4]]]]))
print(compare([3, [4], 5], [3, [6], 5]))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Does this differ in any way from just doing `a == b`? (Assuming the lists don't contain `None`, which would give you spurious matches like `[1]` and `[1, None]`.)

Comment: @kaya3 To me, this is the foundation of an approach that ultimately does more than just simple comparisons: checks for values at certain depths, specific value types, and even list length.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thank you for your reply, this approach is powerful and works great. I have a few more questions: how can I detect if there's no nested structure inside the starting list? (e.g. [1, '[',']']) Also, how is it possible to call a function inside the same function? I understand what all does but I hardly understand how we can call compare inside compare. How do I inteprete it?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are manipulating lists, not arrays.

The exact meaning of "structure" is a bit vague, I am guessing that you mean that there are either integers or nested lists of the same length, at the same positions.

If that is so, here are some problems:

- As soon as you find two identical things, you `return` and exit. This means that if the first elements are identical, you never compare the second element !

```
>>> array_structure([1,2],[4,[5]])
True
```

Finding the "same structure" at one position isn't enough to deduce that it is true for all indices. You need to keep checking. However, you are right that as soon as you find "different structure", you can safely return, because it is enough to make the structures different overall.

- When you have the same type for both elements, if you have an integer, then you convert them to strings, then compare lengths, otherwise, you compare the lengths. This looks strange to me: Why would you say that `[1]` and `[11]` have different structures ?

```
>>> array_structure([1],[11])
False
```

- What about nested arrays ? maybe `array_structure([1,[2]],[1,[2,[3,4,5,6]]])` should be false, and `array_structure([4,[5,[8,3,0,1]]],[1,[2,[3,4,5,6]]])` should be true ? If you have seen the notion of recursion, this might be a good place to use it.

A good strategy for your problem would be to go over each element, make some tests to check if you have "different structures", and return False if that is the case. Otherwise, don't return, so you can go over all elements. This means that if anything is different, you will have exited during iteration, so you will only reach the end of the loop if everything was identical. At that point, you can return `True`. The bulk of the function should look like:

```
for i in range(<length>):
    if <different structure>:
        return False
return True
```

More tips for later:

- Testing for types in general is not very pythonic. Unless the exercise tells you that you will only ever get integers or lists, you could have other things in these arrays that are not integers and don't have a length. Rather than testing whether the things are ints to deduce if they have a length, you could test for `hasattr(array1[i], 'len')`. This will be `True` if the element is of a type that has a length, and `False` otherwise.
- Each time you have something that looks like `if <condition>: return True else return False` you can be sure it is identical to `return <condition>`. This helps in simplifying code, but in your example, it's not a great idea to change it right away, because you should not be returning when you find `True` to your conditions.
- Each time you have something that looks like `<condition> == False`, it is better and more readable to write `not <condition>`. It is also possible to switch the logic over so that you have a positive condition first, which is often more readable.

Comment: Python does provide a thing called an array in the standard library, but it is specialised for manipulation of numbers and passing them to C type interfaces.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, I was thinking of numpy's arrays. Thanks for the info, I'll edit my answer :)